# How can I trim an image using Magick.net keeping clipping paths if they exist

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, clipping, magick.net

When trimming images with Magick.net (to remove white areas around the main object of the image) and they've got a clipping path, then the path is not synchronized with the new proportions of the image.

[image: Looking at the image with the path selected, in Photoshop, after a trim has been performed]

**Is there a way to handle this using Magick.Net, so that the path still trace the objects that it did before trimming?**

(Magick.net uses ImageMagick for its image processing, so if anyone knows how to do it in ImageMagick, perhaps it's easily "translated" into MagickNet.)

*Adding some more information:*
Here is a link to a simple image with a clipping path in it (I just made a few strokes in Photoshop and made it into a path): 
[Zip archive with sample files in different formats, containing paths](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B00_KEyw2w8dTjFReEJTcjI1SlE/view?usp=sharing).

And below you will find a piece of code that uses Magic.Net for trimming that image, with the resulting displacement of the path.

// Put a reference to Magick.net-Q8-AnyCPU using "nuget"

```
using ImageMagick;
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Temp\Path-test-jpg.jpg";
            MagickNET.SetGhostscriptDirectory(@"C:\Temp\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug");
            using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(path))
            {
                // DPI
                Console.WriteLine(image.Density);
                //// Trim
                image.Trim();

                image.Quality = 99;

                image.Write(@"C:\Temp\test-out.jpg");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can provide a link to an image with such a path?

Comment: The requested link is now present : )

Comment: For trials and errors on the same issue see also: https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/issues/43#issuecomment-293618888

Comment: Using ImageMagic directly (not using the .net wrapper) from a command window results in the same thing, that is just running the trim command on a file like this:
convert src.jpg -trim dest.jpg